# Player in Spaceship

Tags: physics, scripting, unity, rigidbody

I want to realize space game on Unity3d engine. There are some huge spaceships in the void. So, I want players flying in space in weightlessness, but when they go inside any spaceship, they will be under the influence of local gravity field of spaceship (if it is in `On` state).
I going to do it using `addForce()` function applied to `rigidbodies` of players towards spaceship floor. But with this approach Players will be only magnify to a floor, but not to stay on they feet automatically.
**How can I put they on they feet the best way?**
 Or, maybe, anybody knows the completely different approach to solve this custom gravity fields issue?
PS: It will be a multiplayer game with many ships with different orientation in space with a lot of players in them. Each ship has it's own gravity field.

Comment: Why would you add force when unity already has the ability for Gravity? Each rigidbody has an option for Gravity... The hardest thing would be figuring out whether you're in a spaceship or outside it.

Answer (score 3):

Each rigid body has an attribute indicating if it's affected by gravity or not. You can just mark that attribute as true, whenever player enters the spaceship, and later turn it false, when he exits. But that'll limit you with a big limitation. The gravity itself in unity is something global, meaning all entities are affected by same gravity force (if any). This means, even if two spaceships have different rotation, players in both of them, will be affected by same gravity, and they are both pulled towards same direction.

This might not be that much of a problem on it's own, but it depends on your design. For example you might limit all the spaceships so that they all have same rotation (they all share same up vector). In that case you can easily use the built-in gravity function, and get away with it.

But in case you don't want that to happen, and want to leave different ships to have different ups, You should consider applying the gravity yourself. Just note that Gravity is an acceleration, not a force. Meaning when applying you should use "ForceMode.Acceleration". That acceleration could simply be the exact opposite of up direction of current spaceship. I'm talking about "-transform.up" of spaceship. You can also use same Up vector, to rotate player so that gravity actually feels right, aka. player feet are pointing towards gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Under the rigidbody tab in the hierarchy freeze rotation X and Z. This will keep them from falling over. Then you should be able to apply gravity on the Y axis without a problem.